# Reuse inflated view for multiple tabs

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I'm writing an app with multiple tabs. Every tab is a fragment and every tab uses the same layout file. You can change to the next tab by swiping (handled by a SwipeAdapter). Inflating the same layout for every tab again is quite inefficient and makes the app lag. Is there a way to inflate the layout once in the beginning and to reuse the inflated layout for all tabs?

Or alternatively, is there a way to do so with e.g. three inflated layouts? (-> one for each the currently displayed tab and both neighbours, so when you swipe from tab 4 to 5, the inflated layout of tab 3 - which is not needed anymore - is used for tab 6)

I know you can reuse inflated views with a listview, but it wouldn't work here because I want the user to swipe instead of continuous scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Use `RecyclerView` with a `SnapHelper` (works both horizontally and vertically). If you Google it you will find many tutorials.

Alternatively you can use `ViewPager2`, which is in alpha state (if you can wait for it to be stable). It is based in `RecyclerView`, and is an update to the old `ViewPager` to bring it to 2019. See this tutorial for example [Hands on With ViewPager2](http://michaelevans.org/blog/2019/02/07/hands-on-with-viewpager2/). See also [ViewPager2 releases](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) page at Google to keep track of development progress.

Comment: Thanks a lot! RecyclerView with SnapHelper is not ideal because the behaviour is more similar to continuous scrolling than to actual swiping, but it works.

Comment: Glad it helped!